# How to use canvasjs library in Sencha Extjs

Tags: extjs, canvasjs

I could see there are plugins available for d3 charts and highcharts to get used in Sencha ExtJS. But i couldnt find Any for canvasjs. Is there a way to integrate CanvasJS with Sencha Ext JS.

Comment: which version you are using ?

Comment: I am using Sencha 5.6.3 version

Answer (score 1):

CanvasJS only needs a div to render their stuff into.

One super simple way could be like that:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
    layout: 'fit',
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    border: 1,
    style: {
        backgroundColor: '#EEEEEE',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderWidth: '1px'
    },
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function (cmp) {
            Ext.Loader.loadScript({
                url: 'https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js',
                onLoad: function () {
                    console.log('ok, lets create the chart..');
                    cmp.createChart();
                },
                onError: function () {
                    console.log('canvasJS not loaded');
                }
            });
        }
    },
    createChart: function () {
        var htmlIdOfCmp = this.id;
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(htmlIdOfCmp, {
            animationEnabled: true,
            theme: "light2",
            title: {
                text: "Simple Line Chart"
            },
            axisY: {
                includeZero: false
            },
            data: [{
                type: "line",
                dataPoints: [{
                    y: 450
                }, {
                    y: 414
                }, {
                    y: 520,
                    indexLabel: "highest",
                    markerColor: "red",
                    markerType: "triangle"
                }, {
                    y: 460
                }, {
                    y: 450
                }, {
                    y: 500
                }, {
                    y: 480
                }, {
                    y: 480
                }, {
                    y: 410,
                    indexLabel: "lowest",
                    markerColor: "DarkSlateGrey",
                    markerType: "cross"
                }, {
                    y: 500
                }, {
                    y: 480
                }, {
                    y: 510
                }]
            }]
        });
        chart.render();
    }
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2k59

This is an example for ExtJS6.